# Download reports from the Microstrategy with filtering

Tags: microstrategy

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/servlet/mstrWeb?evt=4001&src=mstrWeb.4001&reportID=48C05A5F4CCF82CC07F4A1BE2D023FE5&visMode=0&reportViewMode=1&messageID=9850FBA54B678E5B6B66A4B1E527B7B5&stateID=0
```

This sample URL displays the report executed and saved in the archive. Before downloading, I need to specify an additional condition on one of the columns. For example, City = Samplesity How can this be implemented with the help of Microstrategy url api?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view filter (with a prompt) in the report and answer the prompt via MicroStrategy URLAPI. The problem would be that the prompt will be showed also to the users (if the report is executed with a subscription, then no problem).

Using a report in this way doesn't make much sense to me, better in this case to use a cube and create a report with a prompted view filter on top of it.

---

If by "saved in the archive" you mean stored in the History List then there is not much to do here. The History List contains an execution of a report, you cannot really modify it.

If you are looking for a way to filter on old version of your data you have to find another solution, like keeping historical version of the data.